# How to run same docker images twice

Tags: docker, port, graylog2

I am using this docker command for running graylog2.

```
docker run -t -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 graylog2/allinone
```

I want to run another graylog2 in same server and I run new command with different port numbers as

```
docker run -t -p 9001:9000 -p 12202:12201 graylog2/allinone
```

It's not working because of port conflict.

I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:12900
```

Comment: I am getting Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:12900 error

Comment: anyway I would add `--name=ports_9000` and `--name=ports_9001` or `--name=graylock1` or such to my run command, see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow before. I don't understand the error though - where do you see the error and which container/port should it be connecting to? Why do you think there is a port conflict?

Comment: you run with `-t` so you have a tty, but no `-i`  "-i, --interactive=false    Keep STDIN open even if not attached" so you do not have a stdin, you shoudl try running with `-it`

Comment: You need to include a lot more information. The error message you're giving says you're trying to connect to port `12900` which is not one of the ports you're binding two with the two containers. So...of course you can't connect?

Comment: Thanks guys, The problem is solved. It's about firewall settings :) only port 9000 open to end users. By the way the error "Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:12900" still continue but it doesn't matter, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Use `docker run --name="new_name" -d imagename`

Use different port for mapping from container to host or use host networking.